# Sonarlint is giving error on volatile object reference when using double locking for Singleton class in updated 4.1 version

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a already implemented Singleton class earlier which was using double locking mechanism for Singleton instance but we got an SonarLint error of `Double-checked locking should not be used (squid:S2168)` on double locking code.

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton singleton;

private Singleton() {
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (singleton == null) {
        synchronized (Singleton.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

}

As a fix of this issue, I thought of putting `volatile` keyword before Singleton object reference like below.

```
private static volatile Singleton singleton;
```

But after making this field as volatile SonarLint is giving error `Non-primitive fields should not be "volatile" (squid:S3077)`

Does this mean now it is not good practice to make object reference as volatile as most of the example of singleton available are like mentioned code example?

Answer (score 2):

About your try, Sonar gives indeed the `volatile` field [as workaround](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/multi-threading/RSPEC-2168) but it looks like that according to new issue when you use it, it contradicts itself....
Not obvious : )

> but we got an SonarLint error of Double-checked locking should not be
>   used (squid:S2168) on double locking code.

I would remove the double checked locking that is really error prone and verbose.
Eager initialization is thread safe and is in most of case fine :

```
public class Singleton {

    private static final Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {   
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

The lazy way with the holder class is an alternative too (while I generally avoid because  the laziness is often not a requirement) :

```
public class Singleton {

    private static class SingletonHolder{
        static final Singleton singleton = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {   
        return SingletonHolder.singleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: How we know that "Eager initialization is thread-safe"? Is it just for the `static` keyword?

Comment: Yes ! Static initialization is done once and before any instantiation of the class.